# CreateBundle installation is causing errors

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, symfony-cmf

I am following the instructions at: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/cookbook/installing_configuring_inline_editing.html

When I try to do a cache clear, I am getting:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]  
  Unrecognized options "phpcr_odm, image" under "cmf_create"
```

Are the instructions outdated?

Comment: Did you install `"symfony-cmf/create-bundle": "1.0.*"` version?

Comment: "symfony-cmf/create-bundle": "1.0.*"    Minimum stability DEV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the [Configuration](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/CreateBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) on Github it does look like those are out of date.

There looks to be a more up to date config at http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/create.html#configuration

Comment: Qoop is correct, the cookbook entry is indeed outdated. we are currently in a thorough rewrite of the whole doc, and plan to release stable versions of the cmf next week. i added an issue to the documentation github project to remind us to update the cookbook as well: https://github.com/symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf-docs/issues/283

Comment: Awesome. I am looking forward to it.